# how to set parent function's variable value from nested function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I am still beginner with angularjs. may be it is a silly question for you. i am working with x-editable angularjs, my problem is i am not able to set value in nested function my code as below.

1. starting value of this.error is false.
2. in nested then function if i found error it should be updated to true.
3. but out side the function when i will check the value of error it is still false.

`

```
 $scope.checkUserName = function(userName) {  
  // default value is false.
  this.error = false;
  var _this = this;
  IAPIUserDetailService.checkUserName(userName,$scope.user.id)
            .then(
                function( userResponse) {
                    if (userResponse.code == 400) {
                         // i have to update value here
                        _this.error = 'user already exist';  

                    }
                });
     // if there is an error still the value of error variable is false.
     if(this.error !==  false){
        $scope.editableForm.$setError('username', 'username already exist');
     }
  };
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use this in this example, and as Raman pointed due to asyn nature of API call you can only check for the variable after the response has arrived. So you need to rewrite your code:

```
$scope.checkUserName = function(userName) {  
  // default value is false.
  IAPIUserDetailService.checkUserName(userName,$scope.user.id)
            .then(
                function( userResponse) {
                    if (userResponse.code == 400) {
                         // i have to update value here
                       // if there is an error still the value of error variable is false.
                       $scope.editableForm.$setError('username', 'username already exist');
                    }
                });

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the above code there are some mistakes.

> 1. IAPIUserDetailService.checkUserName() is a service call that is returning  a promise object that is asynchronous so the next line would be executed without waiting for the response of the service call. So Check the value after getting the response only.
> 2. One more thing the `this and _this are not two way bounded` so check the value of `_this` instead of `this`.